# Conditional sidebar based on search terms

Tags: wordpress

If someone searches the term  `xperia z1` the url pattern will be as follows:

> domain.com/?s=xperia+z1

Is there away to show a different sidebar based on a phrase from the search pattern?
In the example above, i would like the `sony` sidebar to be displayed.

- IF search term contains "xperia" (or anything containing the word "xperia")  show  sony sidebar
- IF search term    contains "lumia" (or anything containing the word "lumia")  show  nokia sidebar

and so on.

I managed to get it working:

```
<?php if ( isset($_GET['s']) && $_GET['s']=="xperia")  { ?>
<?php get_sidebar('sony'); ?>
<?php } else { ?>  

<?php if ( isset($_GET['s']) && $_GET['s']=="lumia")  { ?>
<?php get_sidebar('nokia'); ?>
<?php } else { ?>  

<?php get_sidebar('left'); ?>
<? } ?><? } ?>
```

The problem is that I want wildcard matching. The current code is specific to  "xperia"
I want it to also fire in case someone searches "xperia 123"

I know in .htaccess the rule would be:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)s=.*?xperia[^&]*(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^ /blahblah/blah/? [L,R]
```

But I do not know how to duplicate that into the PHP code.

I tried:      `<?php if ( isset($_GET['s']) && $_GET['s']==".*?xperia[^&]*(?:&|$)")  { ?>`
without luck of course.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead of your:

```
<?php if ( isset($_GET['s']=='xperia+z1'))  { ?>
 <?php  dynamic_sidebar('sony'); ?> 
<?php } else { ?>  
<?php if ( isset($_GET['s']=='nokia'))  { ?>
 <?php  dynamic_sidebar('nokia'); ?>
```

may this help

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '==' (T_IS_EQUAL), expecting ',' or ')'    but i'll play around with the code